# Embed MP3 Audio Files In Web Pages not woking in some machines

Tags: php, embed

I am using below code for Embed MP3 Audio Files In Web Pages,

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=http://d5duwnm1arn0s.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/24396wp10302/files/T---Billa-Theme-Music.mp3" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="600" height="27" quality="best"></embed>
```

it is works fine in some machines. not working in some other machines.
what is the problem?.

Comment: This depends on Flash being installed and won't work where it's missing - e.g. on iOs devices. See e.g. http://jplayer.org for a more versatile solution

Comment: @Pekka but in that machine they have flash players. Need to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed with this lines:

```
       <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="600" height="27" >
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" />
            <param name="FlashVars" value="audioUrl=http://d5duwnm1arn0s.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/24396wp10302/files/T---Billa-Theme-Music.mp3">
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="600" height="27">

                <param name="movie" value="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" />
                <param name="FlashVars" value="audioUrl=http://d5duwnm1arn0s.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/24396wp10302/files/T---Billa-Theme-Music.mp3">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code requires the Flash plugin to be installed, and will therefore not work on systems without the plugin. Use the [`<audio>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-audio-element.html#the-audio-element) to play sound without requiring a plugin. As a fallback entry for old browsers, you can add your current code, like this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://d5duwnm1arn0s.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/24396wp10302/files/T---Billa-Theme-Music.mp3"
          type="audio/mpeg"/>
  <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         flashvars="audioUrl=http://d5duwnm1arn0s.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/24396wp10302/files/T---Billa-Theme-Music.mp3"
         src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf"
         width="600" height="27" quality="best">
  </embed>
</audio>
```